# Whats the last OS X that supported Power PC?

Tags: macos, powerpc

I still have an old Power PC machine and was wondering what the latest OS X build I can install on it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Snow Leopard (OS X 10.6) is also the
>   first Mac OS release since the
>   introduction of [System 7.1.2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_7) that
>   does not support the [PowerPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerPC)
>   architecture, as Apple now intends to
>   focus on [its current line of
>   Intel-based products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple%E2%80%93Intel_architecture).

Thus OS X supported PowerPC up to and including version 10.5 (Leopard).

Answer (score 8):

10.5 Leopard is the last to support PowerPC as far as I know:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X

Answer (score -1):

Snow leopard does support PowerPC applications, this function was dropped with Lion. I base this on one MacBook with Snow Leopard on it works fine with Microsoft Office X, Quake II (OS XVersion), Halo, Roxio Toast Lite 5.2.2.

However on my upgrade MacBook running Lion they are tomb stoned and when you try to run them the message you receive is PowerPcC no longer supported!

Comment: OS X running on PowerPC *hardware* and OS X supporting PowerPC applications is not the same thing.