# Convert Eudora 6.2 on Apple to 2011 Outlook on Apple

Tags: macos, eudora

I have MAC Power PC running OS 10.4.11 with Eudora 6.2.

How can I convert the above to a later MAC OS to run 2011 Outlook email?

Happy to pay for a service, as I am not very technical.

Comment: I have removed your contact information from the post. Feel free to add that to your profile - that way people can get in touch with you, but we're more of a "here's how to solve X" than a matchmaker for services and buyers. You can always search for local consultants at https://locate.apple.com

Answer (score 1):

According to this post ([Whats the last OS X that supported Power PC?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1308/whats-the-last-os-x-that-supported-power-pc)) Power PCs can only use up to 10.5, which is 7 versions prior to the current, and likely not worth attempting to upgrade.

Also, since this OS came out in 2007, it likely does not support modern versions of Outlook (such as 2011), though I did not confirm this.

TL;DR - computer is really too old for any upgrades that you are looking for.   Sorry :(

Comment: This is good information, but I see Mark as asking how to get the data files converted and offers two Machines running two versions of OS X to get the job done as well as leaving it open for a third party service. You're right that upgrading the old machine directly isn't a viable choice - I agree for several reasons in addition to what you mentioned.